# Pass more than 2 parameters to a Solidity Contract constructor using web3

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I need to pass 3+ parameters to a Solidity contract constructor using web3 to deploy it. From the documentation of web3 v0.2x.x it looks like that it only accepts up to two. Can I pass a javascript object from web3 to the constructor and how will the contract interpret it? If it is not possible what are my opitons for multiple constructor arguments using web3 v0.2x.x?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation you're having trouble with? You can pass as many parameters to a constructor as you want.

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract MyCotract.new part @smarx

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the examples. Perhaps they should have included an ellipsis.

Comment: check this one: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/91643/64382